# Terminal says that the wallpaper is changed but I see that it doesn't!

Tags: settings, desktop, wallpaper, gnome

I use a Dell laptop with a docking station with 2 monitors and Loki.
I don't have problem in changing the wallpaper when I use the laptop alone, without docking station and 2 monitors.

When I Use the 2 monitors the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/NewWallpaper.jpg
```

doesn't work.

The funny thing is that suppose I have an "OldWallpaper" as wallpaper and I change it, via the previous command, to "NewWallpaper". If I ask for my actual wallpaper

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

the output is

```
'file:///path/NewWallpaper.jpg'
```

but I still see the OldWallpaper on my desktop!
The same happens if I manually click on the NewWallpaper.jpg and choose "Set as Desktop Background".

I've also tried with dconf Editor and, as before, there is no correspondence between what I see on my desktop (OldWallpaper) and the picture-uri value (NewWallpaper).

Also I've tried with

```
set-wallpaper /path/NewWallpaper.jpg
```

but the output is

```
set-wallpaper: command not found
```

Any idea about what is going on??

Comment: You might have to restart `gala` as well so that it effectively changes the wallpaper. On the other hand, to run `set-wallpaper` you might need to specify the full path: `/usr/libexec/switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell/set-wallpaper`

Comment: Thank for your answer. How I can restart gala? typing from terminal 
DISPLAY=:0 gala --replace & will turn off my screen; also if I try to enter in the TT1 pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 again my screens are completely black and I cannot do anything more.

Moreover I've tried in terminal /usr/libexec/switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell/set-wallpaper /path/NewWallpaper.jpg
but it gives me this error

(set-wallpaper:2671): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2045:14: 'min-height' is not a valid property name


Again, How can I change wallpaper from terminal???